# Simple Android Live Wallpaper with sequence of images - Updated with code

Tags: java, android, android-animation, live-wallpaper

I would like to develop a simple Live Wallpaper with a sequence of images. The only animation required is for each image to fade in and fade out.

All the tutorials I have found online for LWP demonstrate how to use the Draw canvas for fancy animations and drawing. This is not necessary for my app, I only want to iterate through a collection of images.

Being a novice programmer, I need some help learning how to loop through an array of images and how to display them as a wallpaper.

Can anyone share some code or point me towards a good tutorial for this?

**UPDATE**

The LWP loads on my device but the wallpaper does not change. It is stuck on image3, ironman

Here is the code I have so far. I assume I am doing something wrong in draw()

```
public class Wallpaper extends WallpaperService {
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new CercleEngine();
}

class CercleEngine extends Engine {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable drawRunner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }
    };
    private boolean visible = true;
    public Bitmap image1, image2, image3;

    CercleEngine() {
        image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.batman);
        image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.captainamerica);
        image3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ironman);
    }


    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            handler.post(drawRunner);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
        this.visible = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
    }

    public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,
            float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
        draw();
    }

    void draw() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (c != null) {
                c.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(image2, 0, 0, null);
                c.drawBitmap(image3, 0, 0, null);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(drawRunner);
        if (visible) 
        {
           handler.postDelayed(drawRunner, 1000); // delay 1 sec
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way around the looping through an array of images. It would have to be done manually.

One approach that you could adopt is to keep your images in the    /res/drawable
and then use an int[] array to store the resid's of the images and then loop through it.

A well explained tutorial on Live Wallpapers may be found here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Good Luck

Comment: I've looked at the vogella tutorial. I have the live wallpaper on my phone installed but its remains on one image. I'll share my code.

Comment: @tiptopjat are you able to  develop a Live Wallpaper with a sequence of images with fade in and fade out effect.i am also struck with same problem could you plz help me.